# how to delete rows and columns in numpy python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am having trouble creating a function which takes a matrix M as an input and deletes BOTH rows and columns containing the number 0 and giving an output containing the remaining numbers. Any help is much appreciated as I have my programming exam coming up soon.

By "deleting both rows and columns" this is what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Please be aware [so] is not a code-writing service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Comment: If you really have absolutely no idea how to approach this, please at least provide a clear problem statement – such as an actual numpy array declaration, the rows/columns you want removed, and the desired output. Also clarify what parts you do understand, e.g. do you know how to delete *either* rows or columns containing the number 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
              [6,0,8,9,10],
              [11,12,13,14,15],
              [16,0,0,19,20]])

idxs_array = list(np.where(x==0))
idxs_array = [list(dict.fromkeys(x)) for x in idxs_array]

for axis, idxs in enumerate(idxs_array):
    sub_factor = 0
    for idx in idxs:
        x = np.delete(x,idx-sub_factor,axis)
        sub_factor += 1

print(x)
       
# x = [[ 1,  4,  5],
#      [11, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score -2):

### 1. Locate zero elements

First of all, we need to identify the location of the zero elements in the matrix, which can be done easily with `np.where()`.

`np.where` will return the row/column indices of the elements matched specific condition ([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)).

```py
row_idx, col_idx = np.where(arr == 0)
```

### 2. Remove corresponding rows/columns

To remove corresponding rows and columns, there is an easy way to do this, which is indexing ([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)).

That is, you can specify the row (or column) you want to keep with `True`, else it shall be `False`.

```py
print(np.arange(4)[[True, False, True, False]])
# array([0, 2])
```

### 3. Put two things together

Here is a minimal example.

```py
arr = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
                [ 6,  0,  8,  9, 10],
                [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                [16,  0,  0, 19, 20]])
 
row_idx, col_idx = np.where(arr == 0)

rm_row_idx = set(row_idx.tolist())
rm_col_idx = set(col_idx.tolist())

row_mask = [i not in rm_row_idx for i in range(arr.shape[0])]
col_mask = [i not in rm_col_idx for i in range(arr.shape[1])]

arr = arr[row_mask, :]
arr = arr[:, col_mask]

print(arr)

# Shall be:
# array([[ 1,  4,  5],
#        [11, 14, 15]])
```